# How to create a GET route acting as a subscription route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 Web API and would like to create a `GET` endpoint (acting as a subscription) sending data every x seconds. I know that there are tools out there, e.g. SignalR, but I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same result with a simple route. Maybe a stream could help ...

This is my example controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public OkResult SendDataEvery5Seconds()
    {
        return Ok(); // send back an initial response

        // send data every 5 seconds
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is possible with C# but I tried to create a working example using Node showing what I want to achieve:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson'
  });

  setInterval(() => {
      res.write(JSON.stringify(new Date()) + '\n');
  }, 5000);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

running `curl -i http://localhost:3000` should write down a date every 5 seconds.

Comment: Your controller has a `Response` property where you can send response data manually. (`Response.Body`).

Comment: Try writing while loop with thread.sleep and writing data to response. `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(5000); return Ok();}`

Comment: This will exhaust your server as the method will keep running even when client is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it like this.

Server code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-ndjson";

    // you can manage headers of the request only before this line
    await Response.StartAsync(ct);

    
    // cancellation token is important, or else your server will continue it's work after client has disconnected
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some data here\n"), ct);
        await Response.Body.FlushAsync(ct);

        // change '5000' with whatever delay you need
        await Task.Delay(5000, ct);
    }
}
```

Corresponding client code (c# example):

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:5000/");

using var responseReader = new StreamReader(response);


while (!responseReader.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(await responseReader.ReadLineAsync());
}
```